# How to run batch file in remote server(windows 10) from Django Web server

Tags: django, server, django-rest-framework, webserver, remote-access

I am new to Django learning and have fairly understood basic polls app from Django tutorial, Now I ahve below requirement:

I have a basic (server1) Django development web server and another server (server2) which has a python script or a batch file that launches a python application . Assume that the server1 has necessary authentication in place to run the script on server2. All I want to do is, click a button on the django website which would run the python script sitting on server2.

I am really clueless here on how to achieve it, Will Django REST APIs work in this case ? I am not aware of what Django REST APIs do but willing to learn if it solves the purpose. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use concept of `call_command` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)